# less: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, command-line

Somehow the less command seems to have been removed from my system. I'm really not sure how it happened, but I need to get it back. My path seems to be fine, however the less file seems to be missing from my /usr/bin directory.

```
less: command not found
```

As this command is typically preinstalled, I can't find a way to reinstall it. I'm running on OSX 10.8.2.

Any idea where/how I can get this tool back?

Note that I'm talking about the basic less command (like the 'more' command), not the LESS CSS command.

Comment: For the future, be careful about what you're doing when you have `sudo` rights. There'S no other way you could have removed a system binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, backup by TimeMachine is great idea!

Homebrew has a policy of not shipping formulae for commands that already exist on your system (e.g. `less`, `perl`, etc.). To get those, you will need to `tap` into another Homebrew repository:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
```

Now, you can run:

```
brew install less
```

Comment: First thing I tried; gives me: Error: No available formula for less

Comment: So try `brew update` before `brew install less`.

Comment: I have; there is still not a formula for less. Have you been able to install less through brew before?

Comment: Homebrew itself doesn't bundle `less` since it's a duplicate of one of the built-in OS X tools, which Homebrew doesn't ship. cc @Nick

Comment: You guys are right. Try `brew tap homebrew/dupes` before install. I think I will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to try restoring it from a backup.

If that doesn't help, I've [uploaded my `less`](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/84665/download/less) from 10.8.2 on my Dropbox for you to download.

Download it and run the following to make sure it's owned by the right user and has the correct permissions:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/less /usr/bin/less
sudo chown root:wheel /usr/bin/less
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/less
```

You *might* be able to use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) to browse a DMG of a Mountain Lion installer image to search for the `less` binary as well.

Comment: The brew tap worked, but thanks so much for uploading the file just incase!

Comment: No problem. I'd suggest you download it and put it back into `/usr/bin` though. Homebrew installs `less` to a directory that OS X normally isn't aware of, so you could run into problems when `less` is trying to be used from shells that aren't aware of Homebrew at all.